# How to properly select specific columns using belongsToMany?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the `UserModel` which contains this relation:

```php
public function patients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invites', 'tenant_id', 'user_id');
}
```

This relation returns all the `patients` associated to the current logged in user, so if I call this:

```php
auth()->user()->patients()->toSql();
```

it returns this query:

```sql
select
    *
from
    `users`
inner join
    `invites` on `users`.`id` = `invites`.`user_id`
where
    `invites`.`tenant_id` = ?
    and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
```

which is correct. But I would like to use the model like that:

```php
$userModel = new App\Models\Boilerplate\User();
return $userModel::with('patients')->select([
    'users.id',
    'email',
    'last_name',
    'first_name',
    'active',
    'users.created_at',
    'last_login',
]);
```

if I print the last query, I get this:

```sql
select
    `users`.`id`,
    `email`,
    `last_name`,
    `first_name`,
    `active`,
    `users`.`created_at`,
    `last_login`
from
    `users`
where
    `users`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Which is completely different from the first query that is working fine.

If I use `$userModel` the result of course is wrong, it returns all the users available on the table, but the result must be the same of `auth()->user()->patients`.

What I did wrong?

Comment: `auth()->user()->patients()->with(...)->select(...)`? As I said on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223859/how-to-get-pivot-data-using-model), if `auth()->user()` returns an instance of the same model, you can just use the same code. You shouldn't have to call `App\Models\Boilerplate\User()` at all.

Comment: Also, the correct syntax for limiting columns on a relationship would be `with('patients:id,tenant_id,user_id,first_name')`, etc, or a CSV specifying the columns you want to be included.

Comment: `auth()->user()->patients` so you need all the patients of a user but with specific columns?

Comment: @EvangelosBitsilis yes, I would like to use the `UserModel` to achieve this. Didn't tried the solutions proposed by the other users yet

Comment: @sfarzoso what do you mean the `userModel`?  `auth()->user()` returns a user model or you just don't want the currently logged in user but an other one? what's wrong with it?

Comment: @EvangelosBitsilis nothing wrong, I'm learning laravel and I would like to improve this, that's why I asked a question

Comment: @sfarzoso if this is the case and you need only the user's patients with specific columns you can pass an array in the `->get()` method with the columns you need for example `auth()->user()->patients()->get(["email"]);` this will return only the email column of the user's patients

Comment: did my answer work for you ?

Comment: @medilies unfortunately not, I have used `auth()->user()->patients` but is still a mistery for me why doesn't work your code, the error says that the email column cannot be located on the users table, but the users table contains that column so ..

Comment: Using the Relationship `patients` as an attribute returns a `collection` so no further **SQL** filtering after that part. If you want that we debug your issue more than this help us [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The main `select()` must include `id` from `users`.
2. The subquery `select()` must include `user_id` from `patients`

```php
$userModel::select('id', 'and_other_user_columns')
    ->with(['patients' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('user_id', 'and_other_patient_columns');
}])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the with method. But you must include the patients id in your query.

`return $userModel::with('patients:id, email, last_name, first_name, active, last_login')->select(['id','created_at'])->get();`